# .htaccess mod_rewrite loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am working on implementing some mod_rewrite .htaccess rules to create clean URLs.  Specifically, when a user submits a form with a GET request, I am trying to ensure the URL is cleaned via a 301 (currently testing with a 302 to avoid caching).

The problem I have is that my rules are creating an infinite loop.

The rule to redirect the user's get request (to avoid the user seeing ?query1=&query2= in their browser):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^query1=(.*)&query2=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^results.php$ /results/%1/%2? [R=302,NC,L]
```

However, I also have a rule further down to format anyone visiting /results/ to forward to results.php (e.g. from a "back to results" link):

```
RewriteRule results/(.*)/(.*)$ results.php?query1=$1&query2=$2 [NC,L]
```

Full .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^query1=(.*)&query2=(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^results.php$ /results/%1/%2? [R=302,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule results/(.*)/(.*)$ results.php?query1=$1&query2=$2 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Any suggestions as to how I can fix this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rewrite engine loops, so your last rule that rewrites to the query string gets trapped by the first rule when the engine loops. Instead of matching against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable, you need to match against the `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable so that it's not affected by other rewrites:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /results\.php\?query1=([^&]+)&query2=([^&\ ]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^results.php$ /results/%1/%2? [R=302,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule results/(.*)/(.*)$ results.php?query1=$1&query2=$2 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for.  I didn't realize the engine loops, so the behavior I was experiencing makes sense.  I replaced my     %{QUERY_STRING} rule to one that uses    %{THE_REQUEST} per your answer, and it works as expected, now!  Thanks!